# Grouping array from xml by values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

[Example Link](https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year=2014&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p=1&tp=s&md=3&rs=10349&it=1030123459)

Hello, I need to sort usernames between tags **identificador** using the tag **curso** as key, as given in link above. I've tried this solution but there are still out of order.

$dataClip gives me the usernames( identificador) and $dataClipCourse gives me the courses( curso).

EDIT: processXML gives me all usernames(identificadores) and processXMLCourse all courses(curso).

a.soveral

aj.sampaio

aa.reis

a.piedade

ac.tavares

a.meixeiro

acs.pires

ac.vieira

ac.ribeiro

acdo.rodrigues

389

167

450

167

450

450

167

450

167

169

```
$dataClip= processXML($content_b);
$dataClipCourse=processXMLforCourse($content_b);
$new_arr = array();

foreach($dataClipCourse as $dcc=>$dataClip)
{
    $new_arr[$dataClip['identificador']][$dcc]=$dataClip;
}
ksort($new_arr,SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Here is an excerpt of output:

Array ( [] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [1](https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year=2014&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p=1&tp=s&md=3&rs=10349&it=1030123459) => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 389 ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 450 ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 450 ) [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 450 ) [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 450 ) [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 169 ) [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [15] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 389 ) [16] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [17] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [18] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 450 ) [19] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 172 ) [20] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [21] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 167 ) [22] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 450 )

Comment: You're shadowing `$dataClip` inside the foreach with the value iteration variable, so `$dataClip['identificator']` is not indexing your "original" `$dataClip` from the outer scope. Also, what is processXML and processXMLforCourse returning, exactly? I see they must be SimpleXMLElement, but what does the [0] => NNN mean? There doesn't seem to be an 'identificator' key at all.

Comment: @Oliver Hello, i've edited my post. what do you mean by shadowing? What would you suggest?

Comment: Shadowing means that you're hiding access to a variable by declaring a new variable in a different scope. I have to say I may be wrong here as PHP does not have real variable scopes and that would mean that the foreach loop will overwrite your original value of the `$dataClip`. Could you also post a data dump (`print_r`) of the $dataClip and $dataClipCourse arrays? I'm still not sure how the data layout looks. In the end you want the course IDs as the keys in the $new_arr and the names of the persons as values? Like `Array (389 => "a.soveral", 167 => "aj.sampaio", ...)` ?

Comment: @Oliver In the end i would like to have all names belonging to 167 course grouped under it. Same with the other courses. Something like..167=> aj.sampaio
            a.piedade
            as.pires
            ac.ribeiro

     389=>  a.soveral

Comment: So the way to go would be (pseudo code): foreach(person as p) { foreach(people.courses as pc) { add p to courses[pc].peoples } } right? Doing a correct implementation depends heavily on the actual source data format. I guess I could write you a semi-working algorithm where you just have to transform the source data a bit so the input to the algorithm is well formed.

Comment: @Oliver Yes please, totally lost here. I'm only getting everyone without the course order
$new_arr = array();
foreach($dataClip as $p){
 foreach($dataClipCourse as $dcc){
 
  $new_arr[$dataClipCourse[$dcc]]=$p;
  
 }
 print_r($new_arr);
 }
 ksort($new_arr,SORT_NUMERIC);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's assume the input data is in the following format:

```
$people = array( "Name A" => Array(450, 167), "Name B" => Array(629, 450) , ...);
```

So for each person, there is a entry in the `$people` array which has the persons' name as the key and the array of courses she attends as the value. Now, transforming this into a list of courses where the persons are listed next to the course numbers "inverses" the array, so the course number becomes the key and the list of attendees becomes the value:

```
$courses = array( 450 => Array("Name A", "Name B"), 167 = Array("Name A"), 629 => Array("Name B") );
```

This can be accomplished by this algorithm:

```
$courses = array();

// Iterate all persons
foreach( $people as $name => $attendedCourses)
{
    // Iterate all attended courses of this person
    foreach( $attendedCourses as $courseNumber )
    {
        // Check if the current course was already remembered
        if( isset($courses[$courseNumber] ) )
        {
            // Add person to the list of attendees
            $courses[$courseNumber][] = $name;
        }
        else 
        {
            // Create list of attendees with the
            // current person as the single attendee
            $courses[$courseNumber] = array( $name );
        }
    }
}

// Sort by keys
ksort( $courses );

// Output
print_r( $courses );
```

But you'd have to transform your list of SimpleXML nodes into the simpler input format.

Comment: Thank you, but I need it to stay on this format. My script has already other things working basely on simplexml. Unless it could be a simple tranformation, I would have to overhaul everything I've done.

Comment: I guess it should be pretty easy to get the needed values out of the SimpleXML nodes / write a wrapper which provides access to these values based on the SimpleXML data given